# Ссылка через селектор select option value

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Необходимо через селектор select option value организовать ссылки(переход) на страницы файлы которых 1.html, 2.html лежат в той же папке,что и вэб страница с селектором select/
Как изменить адресацию в value под мои условия. Заранее спасибо.Борис.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('select').onchange = function() {window.location = this.value}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1.html">1.html</option>
  <option value="2.html">2.html</option>
  <option value="3.html">3.html</option>
</select>
```